# imdb_id is NULL for all names and titles

Tags: mysql, dump, imdb, imdbpy

I have downloaded sample dump of imdb (mySQL) from imdbpy as mentioned in the following URL:
http://blog.secaserver.com/2013/08/importing-imdb-sample-data-set-mysql/

After installing all the data, i observed that imdb_id is NULL in title and names tables. I have few queries in this:

1. How to fill the imdb_id in those tables?
2. My main intention is to get the poster URLs for movies and headshots for the actors. Is there any simple way to import those URLs in mysql database?
3. What is the use of md5sum in the title and names tables?

Answer (score 1):

The imdbID information is not distributed with the plain text data files, so the NULL values are expected. The field is automatically filled when a Movie object is asked for it's imdbID, doing a remote query (with a title match).
I'm not aware of any easy and fast way to populate it, sorry.

So, to aswer your questions:

1. just do a (remote) query as described here: http://sourceforge.net/p/imdbpy/mailman/message/1053124/ (it goes without saying that you can populate the complete table).
2. headshots and posters URLs are no available in the plain text data files; you have to use IMDbPY to access the data from the website.
3. a checksum of the 'long imdb canonical name' or 'long imdb name', mostly used to preserve imdb_id values during the upgrade of an existing database (importing a new set of plain text data files).